# Why are Carto basemaps more performant than Mapbox maps?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, deck.gl

I'm following the icon [tutorial](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/tree/8.4-release/examples/website/icon) for Deck.gl in React. I swapped out the MAP_STYLE from a Carto basemap, `https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json`, to a Mapbox basemap, `mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9`.

I've omitted much of the code, but here's the return function for reference:

```
  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={[layer]}
      views={MAP_VIEW}
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={{ dragRotate: false }}
      onViewStateChange={hideTooltip}
      onClick={expandTooltip}
    >
      <StaticMap
        reuseMaps
        mapStyle={mapStyle}
        preventStyleDiffing={true}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      />
      {renderTooltip(hoverInfo)}
    </DeckGL>
```

The issue comes when I try to move around the map. When I use the Carto basemap, the movement is quite smooth, whereas there's a noticeable lag in the Mapbox basemap. Here are some gifs for illustration:

Carto:
[image]

Mapbox:
[image]

I want to use Mapbox since I find their layers more aesthetic, but I can't seem to make it as performant as some examples, such as [this](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA#1.07/3.4/32.3) one.

Are there any additional optimizations that I could make to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across the same issue, it seems the easiest fix is to export the style from the Mapbox style builder and import the theme as a JSON in your React project.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @SteveBennett unfortunately I know. I wasn't able to find the technical solution; that's why I'm leaving the question open for answering by someone who might.